# Intercom (client side) JavaScript "on message send" callback/event?

Tags: javascript, intercom

Does anyone know how to hook into an Intercom callback on the frontend that will let me know when a user has actually sent a message and not just when they open the chat box initially? We have a modal that calls Intercom('show') when a user clicks a "Learn More" CTA in an upgrade modal to trigger the chat and I want to use Intercom('update', { data to update }) to set their intercom profile data once they actually send a message to tell Intercom "this message was sent by a chatbox that was opened via a specific modal and not initiated by the user themselves clicking the intercom launcher".

For example, we have "qualification" data in the Intercom dashboard that checks a user to see if they have the "modal_trigger" object key populated with a value, for example "upgrade-modal" to tell us that the person messaging us came from an upgrade trigger and not just that they clicked the launcher on their own.

I know there is the Intercom('onShow')/Intercom('onHide') callbacks, but I need to use Intercom('update') to set the data when they actually send the message (for example a hypothetical Intercom('onSend') callback) but can't seem to find anything that is JS client side only.

Any help is appreciated!